# _lodash, sort by 2 fields(numbers, time)

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash, underscore.js

I have an array of object with data:

```js
items = [
   {
     ....someFields
     timeFrom: {
       hour: 17,
       minute: 15
     }
   },
   {
    ....someFields
     timeFrom: {
       hour: 12,
       minute: 32
     }
   },
   {
    ....someFields
     timeFrom: {
       hour: 17,
       minute: 15
     }
   },
    ....someFields
     timeFrom: {
       hour: 17,
       minute: 35
     }
   }
];

_.sortBy(items, o => o.timeFrom.hour);
```

How I can sort is by  **timeFrom** **hour** and **minute** fields using **lodash**.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lodash supports an array of *iteratees* to run each element through. It also supports the object reference syntax of `_.get()`

```js
_.sortBy(items, ["timeFrom.hour", "timeFrom.minute"]);
```

---

Of course, you hardly need an entire 3rd party library for something like this

```js
// normalise to minutes
[...items].sort(
  (a, b) =>
    (a.timeFrom.hour * 60 + a.timeFrom.minute) -
    (b.timeFrom.hour * 60 + b.timeFrom.minute)
);
```

Comment: Alternatively you could do `[...items].sort(
  (a, b) =>
    60*(a.timeFrom.hour - b.timeFrom.hour) +a.timeFrom.minute - b.timeFrom.minute
);` as this will also work correctly with data like this: `[{timeFrom:{hour:0,minute:70},{timeFrom:{hour:1,minute:5}}}`.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann I'd considered that too. There's plenty of options